# Multiple Access to the Same Stream

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

**Context**

The code below represents an abstraction where the `MyClass` is some kind of a download manager.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

Future<void> main() async {
  MyClass().test().listen((v) => print('t1: $v')).onError(print);
  final commomClass = MyClass();
  commomClass.test().listen((v) => print('t2: $v')).onError(print);
  commomClass.test().listen((v) => print('t3: $v')).onError(print);
}

class MyClass {
  bool _isDownloadInProgress = false;
  int _i = 0;
  StreamController<int> _sc;
  
  Stream<int> test() async* {
    if (_isDownloadInProgress) {
      throw Exception('Download already in progress');
    } else {
      _sc = StreamController<int>();
    }
    
    Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      (t) {
        if (_i == 4) {
          _isDownloadInProgress = false;
          _i = 0;
          _sc.close();
          t.cancel();
        } else {
          _sc.add(_i++);
        }
      },
    );

    yield* _sc.stream;
  }
}
```

**Question**

I expected that after executing this code, it would generate the values t1 and t2 and the output t3 would generate 'Download already in progress' only once. For example:

```
t1: 0
t2: 0
t3: Download already in progress
t1: 1
t2: 1
t1: 2
t2: 2
t1: 3
t2: 3
```

But it outputs all **four** `t1` values, **eight** `t3` values and **no** 'Download already in progress' message:

```
t1: 0
t3: 0
t3: 1
t1: 1
t3: 2
t3: 3
t1: 2
t3: 0
t1: 3
t3: 1
t3: 2
t3: 3
```

For me, the `t1` values would output correctly, the `t2` also would output correctly, and the `t3` would output the 'Download already in progress' message because as everything is being run asynchronous, it would be trying to 'download' something that is already being downloaded (since the `test()` method was called on the same instance of the `MyClass`).

What am I missing?

Comment: Well you are missing the code for one.

Comment: My bad hahaha..

Comment: Please put the code as text not as image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, your code never sets `_isDownloadInProgress` to true, so there is no reason that "Download already in progress" would ever appear.

This actually is what's causing the second error. When you call the t3 `listen`, since `_isDownloadInProgress` is always false, this results in `_sc` getting overwritten in addition to a new `Timer.periodic` getting enqueued. When each timer triggers, it references `_sc`, which is now the one containing the t3 `listen`, so you end up with two timers pushing events to the same stream controller, which is why you see double the t3 events.

Simply setting `_isDownloadInProgress = true` prior to the timer being instantiated is sufficient to get the expected results:

```dart
class MyClass {
  bool _isDownloadInProgress = false;
  int _i = 0;
  StreamController<int> _sc;
  
  Stream<int> test() async* {
    if (_isDownloadInProgress) {
      throw Exception('Download already in progress');
    } else {
      _sc = StreamController<int>();
    }
    
    _isDownloadInProgress = true; // Add this line
    Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      (t) {
        if (_i == 4) {
          _isDownloadInProgress = false;
          _i = 0;
          _sc.close();
          t.cancel();
        } else {
          _sc.add(_i++);
        }
      },
    );

    yield* _sc.stream;
  }
}
```

Results:

```
Exception: Download already in progress
t1: 0
t2: 0
t1: 1
t2: 1
t1: 2
t2: 2
t1: 3
t2: 3
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice this... But the explanation about _sc getting overwritten was nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set `_isDownloadInProgress = true;` inside the function.

Try:

```dart
if (_isDownloadInProgress) {
    throw Exception('Download already in progress');
} else {
  _sc = StreamController<int>();
  _isDownloadInProgress = true;
}
```

#### Output

```
Exception: Download already in progress
t1: 0
t2: 0
t1: 1
t2: 1
t1: 2
t2: 2
t1: 3
t2: 3
```

You can make `t3` more interesting by delaying its start:

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2),
      () => commomClass.test().listen((v) => print('t3: $v')).onError(print));
```

#### Output

```
t1: 0
t2: 0
Exception: Download already in progress
t1: 1
t2: 1
t1: 2
t2: 2
t1: 3
t2: 3
```